# React Native - Sets the state of the child component directly on the parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components, state

I want to ask a question. In the case I have encountered, I have many components that use state inside. So I don't declare the state of the component in the parent component, because I don't want the parent component to appear to have multiple states. My question is can I set the state value of each child component in the parent component?

Here's a code sample of what I want to do:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Switch} from 'react-native';

const Parents = () => {
  {/**
    Can I set state (setIsEnabled) directly on the parent component?

    For example:
    <Child active={true} onValueChange={() => setIsEnabled(!isEnabled)} />
  */}
  return (
    <Child active={true} />
  );
}

const Child = ({active}) => {
  const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = React.useState(active);

  return (
    <Switch
      trackColor={{
        false: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)',
        true: 'rgba(66, 133, 244, 0.54)',
      }}
      thumbColor={isEnabled ? 'rgb(66, 133, 244)' : 'rgb(250, 250, 250)'}
      ios_backgroundColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)"
      onValueChange={() => setIsEnabled(!isEnabled)}
      value={isEnabled}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for

```
import React from 'react';
import {Switch} from 'react-native';

const Parents = () => {
  {/**
    Can I set state (setIsEnabled) directly on the parent component?

    For example:
    <Child active={true} onValueChange={() => setIsEnabled(!isEnabled)} />
  */}
  return (
    <Child active={true} />
  );
}

const Child = (props) => {
  const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = React.useState(props.active);

  return (
    <Switch
      trackColor={{
        false: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)',
        true: 'rgba(66, 133, 244, 0.54)',
      }}
      thumbColor={isEnabled ? 'rgb(66, 133, 244)' : 'rgb(250, 250, 250)'}
      ios_backgroundColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)"
      onValueChange={() => setIsEnabled(!isEnabled)}
      value={isEnabled}
    />
  );
}
```